# Simple makefile with directory for object files.

Tags: makefile

I  have written very simple makefile and I can not figure out why it works incorrectly. I wanted to put .o files in different directory.
Unfortunately my .o files are not created in ./obj/Debug but they are in current working directory the same directory where makefile is. Should those directories be created before invoking *make*? I can't locate my error.

```
SHELL = /bin/sh 

.SUFFIXES:
.SUFFIXES: .c .o

CC := gcc       # compiler type 

CFLAGS = -Wall
Version := Debug
oPath = obj/$(Version)

app: header1.o main.o
    $(CC) -Wall -o -v app $(oPath)/main.o $(oPath)/header1.o

$(oPath)/%.o: %.c header1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I have also tried:

```
$(oPath)/%.o: %.c header1.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $(oPath)/$@
```

but with no success.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
app: header1.o main.o
```

tells make that `app` depends on `header1.o` and `main.o` in the current working directory, so it uses the implicit rules to build them, whereupon they appear in that directory. To fix this, use

```
app: $(oPath)/header1.o $(oPath)/main.o
```

`make` will then use your pattern rule to build `$(oPath)/header1.o` and `$(oPath)/main.o` before running the recipie for `app`.